# The type of name space "" could not be found VS2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, dll, web

I created a WCF Service DLL in C++.
I wanted to use it in C# ASP.NET Form Website.

I have already added reference to website.
But when I use "using" in .aspx.cs file.
There is a error "The type of name space "" could not be found"

The DLL works well in console application. Only cannot work in website.

Comment: When you say you've already added a reference to the website, how did you add the reference?  Via Add Service Reference?  Is the WCF Service DLL hosted somehow?  Can you post a snippet of your code with the using statement?